# bs4) How many request does occur for each time parsing html?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I got the html source by `requests` and I want to parse them as blow(sudo code):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.example.com', headers=headers, params=params)

html_doc = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

item_ls = []
for elem in soup.select('.items'):
    item_ls.append(elem.text)
```

But I am not sure whether `BeutifulSoup` obj. requests data, every time I iterate elements by `for loop`(especially when executing `elem.text`) or I can use the obj. as the local html source, unlike `selenium`.

I need to minimize the number of requests to avoid getting blocked.

Comment: The only time an HTTP request is happening in your code is in the `requests.get` call. Everything else is local.

Comment: @rdas Thanks for your answer! Where could I find related fact? I couldn't find it in the official doc.

Comment: Bs4 is a html parser. Once you get the html from `requests.get`, everything is local - because __you already have the whole HTML__. Selenium may be making extra HTTP calls since the webdriver can also execute javascript - which makes more http calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. BeautifulSoup does not make additional HTTP calls - it's just a HTML parser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.example.com', headers=headers, params=params)  # <- the only HTTP call being made here

html_doc = response.text  # <- You have the whole HTML here
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

item_ls = []
for elem in soup.select('.items'):  # <- Everything is local
    item_ls.append(elem.text)
```

Selenium works a bit differently. Since the selenium webdriver is more of a browser, it runs the javascript embedded in the HTML as well - which may make additional HTTP calls.